# powershell sorting really large collection of objects

Tags: sorting, powershell, collections

I am trying to generate histograms from a very large collection of objects (-gt 250k).  I need to sort the collection on a property of each object.  My line of script looks like:

```
$ch = $ch | sort TotalCount -descending  <br>
```

where `$ch[x].totalcount` would be some integer.

The script works but it takes over an hour to sort and consumes 6GB of memory.  How do I speed up the process?

I've done some searching for a solution and several web sites suggest using [array]::sort as it is much quicker.  As this is a collection of objects, I'm not sure how I would use a static `System.Array` sort method.  Even if I could, I don't see how to make the array descending (although reversing the result should be pretty simple).

Any suggestions on how to sort really large collections with powershell?

Answer (score 0):

Let's create an array with 2500 elements. Each element of the array is an object containing the property `totalCount` and we assign an integer to it.

```
$array = @()
1..2500 | % {
    $array += New-Object pscustomobject -Property @{
        totalCount = $_;
    }
}
```

Now let's sort this array and measure the total time for executing the command.

We start with the classic `Sort-Object` using the `-descending` parameter:

```
(Measure-Command {
    $array = $array | Sort-Object TotalCount -descending
}).TotalSeconds
```

Total time in seconds is : 0.1217965

Let's now use the method Reverse of the class System.Array : `[Array]::Reverse()`

```
(Measure-Command {
    [Array]::Reverse([array]$array)
}).TotalSeconds
```

Total time in seconds is : 0.0002594

Quite a difference!

Let's now see other possibilities, lets create a `System.Collections.ArrayList`

```
$array = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
1..2500 | % {
    $o = New-Object pscustomobject -Property @{
        totalCount = $_;
    }
    [Void] $array.Add($o)
}
```

And we rince and repeat. We first use the Reverse method of the class System.Collections.ArrayList, then we pass the collection to the Reverse method of System.Array.

```
(Measure-Command {
    $array.reverse()
}).TotalSeconds
```

Total time in seconds is : 0.0002459

Slight improvement, but pretty similar overall.

Now we typecast the system collection and use `[Array]::Reverse()`

```
(Measure-Command {
    [Array]::Reverse([array]$array)
}).TotalSeconds
```

Total time in seconds is : 0.0008172
Over twice as much time. This clearly shows it wasn't a good idea, so we scrap it.

Conclusion:

A System.Array with `[Array]::Reverse()` is definitely faster than `Sort-Object`, however keep in mind that System.Array is immutable, so if building the array is part of the performance issue, I'd definitely recommend using `System.Collections.ArrayList` since it's mutable.

Answer (score 0):

[array]::reverse() is NOT sorting the array in any way.

Comment: if you want it sorted fast, then do this:
     

    measure-command {

    $array = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    1..2500 | % {
        [Void] $array.Add([tuple]::create([int]$_))
    }
    $array.sort()
    
    }